# Downloading pdf file from live website results in encoded text in the browser

Tags: php, file, pdf, download

I use this code to download pdf files from my website locally but when I publish my site the browser opens encoded text instead downloading my file. Any ideas?[this is what the browser opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W7Vo.jpg)

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $filename =  basename($_GET['id']);
    $filepath = 'images/' . $filename;
    if(!empty($filename) && file_exists($filepath)){

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filepath));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));

            readfile($filepath);
            exit;

    }
    else{
        echo "This File Does not exist.";

    }
}

 ?>
```